# Is there a way to access an After Effects audio layer's sample rate or waveform data?

Tags: audio, after-effects, sample-rate, audiowaveform

I'm trying to write a script, and one of the steps includes using the audio's sample rate as well as its audio waveform data.

I did a lot of research, and for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this nor if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar need as you, doesn't look like AE is designed for use case. In script you can access an Effect's *parameters* and even change them programmatically, but reading the effect's *output* is not possible in — not out of the box anyway per [AE docs](https://ae-expressions.docsforadobe.dev/effect.html?highlight=effect#effect-param-name).

This is a limitation designed into the product, not really a technical impossibility. I'm curious if the developer platform would allow the build of a custom audio analyzer that would make the output accessible to script... my guess is it's possible but would require substantial work.